# Check Html fragment nullity with Play Framework 2.3.0

Tags: templates, playframework-2.3, twirl

I have a tag in my application with the following structure :

```
@(
    columns: Integer
)(header: Html)(body: Html)

<table>
    @if(header != null) {
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @header
            </tr>
        </thead>
    }
    // Body and foot here
</table>
```

And I use it in my template like this :

```
@tags.Table(5) { } {
    // My content here
}
```

The previous code does not work : even if I let the brackets empty, the `<thead></thead>` is displayed. So how to check that the `header` is not empty, null... and how to declare my tag in my template ?
Maybe I'm wrong declaring it with `{ }` ?

If I declare it with `{}`, I have the following error :

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: play.twirl.api.Html
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The twirl template compiler is inferring the empty braces as a call-by-value parameter that returns `Unit`. You can't just leave the braces empty and expect it to pass `null` instead.

Simply pass an empty `Html` object as the `header`, and check that the `body` of the `header` is non-empty before printing it.

```
@(columns: Int)(header: Html)(body: Html)
<table>
    @if(header.body.nonEmpty) {
        <thead>
            <tr>@header</tr>
        </thead>
    }
    @* ... etc .. *@  
</table>
```

And call it like this:

```
@tags.Table(5)(HtmlFormat.empty){
    @* content here *@
}
```

Comment: You should change `(HtmlFormat.empty)` for `{HtmlFormat.empty}`

Comment: Note that you may have to trim the content of the body to avoid empty Strings. In my case I used `@if(!header.body.trim.isEmpty)` . See more on https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.twirl.api.Html